# Is there a bash command that opens VS Code with the Terminal pane already open?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I have created an alias in `~/.bashrc` (see below) so that I can run a command in VS Code's integrated Terminal to open a given folder in the current window. However, when the window opens the requested folder, the integrated Terminal pane is often closed. My workaround is to press Ctrl-`, once the window is ready, but it would be nice to have the Terminal pane reopen automatically every time.

Is there something that I can add to the bash function below that can do this?

```
cdcode () {
  cd "$1"
  code -r .
}
```

Comment: In my case ``-r`` option is opening ``code`` with the terminal panel open.

Comment: I see this happening sometimes. I am guessing that it occurs when the Terminal panel was open the last time this particular folder was open. I would like to see the Terminal panel open every time.

Comment: Maybe you could try using ``expect`` program.

Comment: try experimenting with ``xdotool``